# Java.- Sacar logaritmo base e 2 de N

Tags: java, condiciones, bucles

No tengo idea de como hace este programa y queria ayuda para realizarlo porque no entiendo como se debe hacer porque me lo piden hacer con condicionales o ciclos.

Ejemplo:

```
8
```

salida:

```
3
```

este ejercio viene de la siguiente forma:

*El logaritmo base 2 de un número es el número de veces que se tiene que multiplicar el 2 por sí mismo para alcanzar dicho número. Por ejemplo, log2⁡(2)=1,log2⁡(4)=2,log2⁡(8)=3 y así sucesivamente. Escribe un programa que calcule el logartimo base 2 de un entero N.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]usa esto

```
math.log10(numero)/math.log10(base)
```

ej:

```
math.log10(8)/math.log10(2)=3
```

Comment: Al margen de que la pregunta es mala en contenido pues no expone intento alguno y es seguro quede cerrada, no dejemos que la respuesta se quede corta en calidad, te invito a que leas [answer], edites y expliques tu código